# How does LaTex calculate \linewidth in a twocolumn document?

Tags: geometry, layout

I want to calculate the ideal size of figures that I export from R and include in LaTeX documents (so the text size of the figure labels is in a known proportion to the font size of the resulting document). However, for twocolumn documents I don't know how LaTeX calculates \linewidth. Is there a formula on how to calculate this? I would need something like:

```
(paperwidth - margins)/2 - distance_of_the_columns_as_a_function_of_font_size
```

Of course, I could compile the pdf and include

```
\the\linewidth
```

to get the linewidth of the current document (which I could then provide manually to R), but I want to write a R script that I can run "blindly" and that calculates the required values from the plain .tex file automatically.

Edit: I tested

```
\the\columnsep
```

for 8pt, 10pt, 11pt and 12pt article and scrartcl documents and always got *10pt*, hence I assume the value is constant for regular cases. This will make things fairly easy, since `\columnwidth`will then be:

````
(\paperwidth - margins - 10pt)/2```
````

Comment: `\linewidth` doesn't have a fixed value: it changes if you're in a list environment, for instance. What you want is `\columnwidth`.

Comment: Thanks, yes I think with the answer of David I'll get the correct results when I implement a calculation of \columnsep. Then I'll just use *(paperwidth - margins - columnsep)/2* for ```\columnwidth```. I think the number of font sizes and paper formats I use is limited, so I can just include the respective ```\columnsep```-values in an *if then else* statement (y)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The calculation is

```
\def \twocolumn {%
  \clearpage
  \global\columnwidth\textwidth
  \global\advance\columnwidth-\columnsep
  \global\divide\columnwidth\tw@
  \global\hsize\columnwidth
  \global\linewidth\columnwidth
```

That is `\linewidth` is `\columnwidth` which is half of `\textwidth` after subtracting the column sep (10pt in article class).

`\textwidth` is set in each document class in different ways (and is often re-set by packages such as `geometry`)  by default, in `article` class with the default `10pt` option it is set by

```
\if@compatibility
  \if@twocolumn
    \setlength\textwidth{410\p@}
  \else
    \setlength\textwidth{345\p@}
  \fi
\else
  \setlength\@tempdima{\paperwidth}
  \addtolength\@tempdima{-2in}
  \setlength\@tempdimb{345\p@}
  \if@twocolumn
    \ifdim\@tempdima>2\@tempdimb\relax
      \setlength\textwidth{2\@tempdimb}
    \else
      \setlength\textwidth{\@tempdima}
    \fi
  \else
    \ifdim\@tempdima>\@tempdimb\relax
      \setlength\textwidth{\@tempdimb}
    \else
      \setlength\textwidth{\@tempdima}
    \fi
  \fi
\fi
\if@compatibility\else
  \@settopoint\textwidth
\fi
```

which is more or less 345pt or 2in less than `\paperwidth`